# If executing the variable fails then stop query - SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How would I convert this logic into a SQL statement?

```
IF @GrantSQL is successful, then continue to insert, if not stop query
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GrantSql NVARCHAR(500)

     SET @GrantSql = 'EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember [' + @LoginName + '], ''sysadmin'''

     EXEC sp_executesql @GrantSql

     -- IF @GrantSQL is successful, then continue to insert, if not stop query
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO....
     END
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @GrantSql INT

EXEC @GrantSql = sp_addsrvrolemember @LoginName, 'sysadmin'

IF GrantSql = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO...
END
```

Comment: In this case it works because `sp_addsrvrolemember` only returns two values, but be aware that the return type of stored procedures is `INT`, not `BIT`.

Comment: Don't use bit unless you have a really good reason to. It takes up a full byte and has all kinds of other issues. The answer is correct and I marked it as such but bit is almost always used to show off and is not more efficient then an int.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

IF @@ERROR <> 0

See the documentation for [@@ERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql).  Also be aware that `@LoginName` could contain something bad, such as '; drop table students;'.  That's a SQL injection vulnerability, and in general you'll want to avoid sp_executesql and parameterize your queries.  See Lobanov's answer, which is better.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GrantSql NVARCHAR(500)

     SET @GrantSql = 'EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember [' + @LoginName + '], ''sysadmin'''


     BEGIN TRY
       EXEC sp_executesql @GrantSql
     END TRY
    --'IF @GrantSQL is successful than continue to insert if not stop query'
    BEGIN CATCH
      PRINT 'Oh man, this happened: '+ @@ERROR
      GOTO allDone
    END

    -- no errors. We're good to continue...
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO....
    END

allDone:
END
```

Comment: sp_addsrvrolemember could return 1 (ERROR !) without exception.

Comment: @Milney - SQL Injection isn't really a problem if you're the one running the SQL code. sp_addsrvrolemember is generally something that you execute  internally; it's rarely made available outside one's organization.

Comment: @AlanBurstein That's a terrible approach to security, would you just leave the money room unlocked because it's in the building? Besides the fact it's easily avoidable and unnecessary in this situation, I think it's best to avoid in principle or atleast point out in an answer people may read and apply in a different context like a public input. The user the application is running as has the ability to add users to the sysadmin role so...

Answer (score -1):

You can use an output parameter with `sp_executesql` to capture the return value of a stored procedure (0 for success, 1 for failure):

```
DECLARE @GrantSql NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT;
SET @GrantSql = 'EXEC @ReturnValue = sp_addsrvrolemember [' + @LoginName + '], ''sysadmin'';';
EXEC sp_executesql @GrantSql, N'@ReturnValue INT OUTPUT', @ReturnValue OUT;

IF @ReturnValue = 0
BEGIN
    ....
END
```

But of course, you don't need dynamic SQL, you could simply use:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT;

EXEC @ReturnValue = sp_addsrvrolemember @LoginName = @LoginName, @rolename = 'sysadmin';
IF @ReturnValue = 0
BEGIN
    ....
END
```

It also seems very unlikely that you would need to bulk add people to the sysadmin role. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but it is probably not the right approach